# .htaccess deny everything except one file on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am using the Laravel platform for my website. What I want to achieve is to show only one web page with some info about the website. All other pages are still in development mode, so i want them to protect with .htaccess.

Here is my .htaccess file, unfortunately it is asking for password for every single page:

```
AuthName "myweb"
AuthUserFile "/home/passwd"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

<Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "start.html">
Allow from all 
Satisfy Any
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If there is some solution with .htaccess it will be great, but if Laravel offers an easy solution (except the maintenance mode) I can except that too.

Thanks in advice !

Comment: Why do you not have a proper development system set up for stuff like this? You should rather not do that kind of work in a live environment in the first place … a mere litle syntax error you introduce while coding could make the whole site “break”, even the parts you actually want to be “live” already.

Comment: This rather naive allow/deny approach won’t work anyway, if your already published page embeds any external resources like stylesheets, scripts or images from your own system … you would have to “allow” those as well.

Comment: yes, you are right that i need to allow those external resources. But still the upon code does not work. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: So does `start.html` actually physically exist as a file - or is that just a route that gets handled by the index.php through rewriting?

Comment: yes, it as a route that get handled by the index.php

Comment: Well then the Files directive won’t catch it to begin with … and since both your already published pages and the unpublished ones are handled by the same index.php, you can not simply apply this on the file level here. HTTP Auth can be triggered and handled inside PHP as well … But again, I would strongly suggest that you stop wasting your time on this, and set up a _proper_ dev system instead of picking and poking at the live system. The new brake system for my car does not get developed and tested while I am driving it either …

Comment: as soon this is only a static page i can create a start.html file and place it in the public/ folder and it will work ?

Comment: The two RewriteConds before the RewriteRule that rewrites the requests to the index.php check if what was requested is a physically existing file or folder first, and _don’t_ rewrite it to the index.php then - so yes, in that case you could give access to that particular static file using the Files directive. But that still won’t solve the problem with any embedded resources, you would have to add each one of those as well.

Comment: I have added this and now it works fine: <Files "*">
Require valid-user
</Files>

<Files "start.php">
Allow from all 
Satisfy Any
</Files>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|css|js|php|swf|swz|xml|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|txt)$">
Allow from all 
Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the top of your routes.php (or web.php depending on version)

```
if (getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') != '192.168.6.3' && !\Request::is('/')) {
    abort(404);
}
```

It says if the Request is not the home screen and the IP address is not my IP address, abort with a 404.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Unfortunately in this situation I can test the website with only known IPs. I am not sure if this is the perfect solution